# CodeChef Matches challenge

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am solving some problems from CodeChef but I am stuck on the [Matches problem](https://www.codechef.com/MAY19B/problems/MATCHS):

> Ari and Rich are playing a pretty confusing game. Here are the rules
>   of the game:
>
> 1. The game is played with two piles of matches. Initially, the first pile contains N matches and the second one contains M matches.
> 2. The players alternate turns; Ari plays first.
> 3. On each turn, the current player must choose one pile and remove a positive number of matches (not exceeding the current number of
>      matches on that pile) from it.
> 4. It is only allowed to remove X matches from a pile if the number of matches in the other pile divides X.
> 5. The player that takes the last match from any pile wins.
>
> Solve(N,M)
>
> 1. If its Ari's turn and N%M==0 then Ari wins else Rich wins.
> 2. If N%M!=0 then player try every possible moves and check if he wins any one of them in end.

My solution uses Dynamic Programmming, so I have used `functools.lru_cache` to save function results. But I am getting TLE error in some test cases.How can I further optimize the code?

```py
from functools import lru_cache 

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def Solve(X,Y,Player=True):
    if X%Y==0:
        return Player
    else:
        temp=X
        X=X%Y
        if Player==Solve(max(X,Y),min(X,Y),not Player):
            return Player
        while temp!=X+Y:
            X=X+Y
            if Player==Solve(max(X,Y),min(X,Y),not Player):
                return Player
        return not Player
```

Comment: Can you give an example input for which it takes too long?

Comment: @PeterTaylor the test cases are not visible.But the range of X and Y is 1 to 10^18

Comment: Rolled back major code edit. See meta on [what you can do after you receive an answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/1402).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whitespace needs a lot of changes to be PEP8-compliant. The capitalisation is also unconventional: functions and variables in Python usually start with a lower-case letter.

---

The meaning of `Player` is not entirely clear, and the logic is hard to follow because of that. The convention for this type of combinatorial game is to denote a position as "N" (**N**ext player wins) or "P" (**P**revious player wins). So I think that `Solve` should be renamed `position_is_N`, and then the `Player` variable becomes unnecessary.

`if condition: return` doesn't need a following `else:`.

The loop can be tidied up considerably with `range` and `any`. I think this is equivalent:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def position_is_N(x, y):
    return x % y == 0 or \
           any(not position_is_N(max(x2, y), min(x2, y))
               for x2 in range(x % y, x, y))
```

A comment about the constraint that `x >= y` would be nice.

---

> range of both X and Y is 1 to 10^18

Consider inputs `10**18, 3` (or other similarly small `y`). How many times might the loop run in the worst case?

As a rule of thumb, for a challenge like this if you need to do anything more than `10**9` times your algorithm is wrong. I can only suggest that you will need a complete rewrite to pass the time limit, so you should build a table of small values and see whether you can spot and prove a pattern. The problem is probably far more about mathematics than programming.

Comment: Player denote turn of player. If Player=True then its Ari's turn else Rich

Comment: I stand by my observation that it's not clear. `ari_moves_next` would be clearer, although then the function should be called something like `ari_wins`.

Comment: I have changed my code to more readable form